# how to efficiently use multiprocessing to speed up huge amount of tiny tasks?

Tags: python, multithreading, vectorization

I'm having a bit trouble in Python `multiprocessing.Pool`. I have two list of `numpy` array `a` and `b`, in which

`a.shape=(10000,3)` 
and 
`b.shape=(1000000000,3)`

Then I have a function which does some computation like

```
def role(array, point):
    sub = array-point
    return (1/(np.sqrt(np.min(np.sum(sub*sub, axis=-1)))+0.001)**2)
```

Next, I need to compute

```
[role(a, point) for point in b]
```

To speed it up, I try to use

```
    cpu_num = 4
    m = multiprocessing.Pool(cpu_num)
    cost_list = m.starmap(role, [(a, point) for point in b])
    m.close
```

The whole process takes around 70s, but if I set `cpu_num = 1`, the processing time decrease to 60s... My laptop has 6 core, for reference.

Here I have two questions:

1. is there sth I did wrong with `multiprocessing.Pool`? why the processing time increased if I set `cpu_num = 4`?
2. for task like this (each for loop is a very tiny process), should I use multiprocessing to speed up? I feel like each time, python fill in `Pool` takes longer than process function `role`...

Any suggestions is really welcome.

Comment: Where did you distribute the computations? Didn't you just create 4 processes with the whole computations to perform? (not familiar with starmap)

Comment: Your code looks correct. Are you sure your 4 cores are free and not busy with other OS-related tasks? You may slow down the entire process if your cores are already busy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiprocessing comes with some overhead (to create new processes), which is why it's not a very good choice when you have lots of tiny tasks, where the overhead of process creation might outweigh the benefit of parallelizing.

Have you considered **vectorizing** your problem? 
In particular, if you broadcast the variable `b` you get there:

```
sub = a - b[::,np.newaxis]  # broadcast b
1./(np.sqrt(np.min(np.sum(sub**2, axis=2), axis=-1))+0.001)**2
```

I believe you could then still reduce the complexity of the last expression a bit, as you're creating the square of a square root, which seems redundant (note that I'm assuming the 0.001 constant value is merely there to avoid some non-sensible operation like division by zero).

Comment: I see sir. But this way it needs a lot of memory (this case would be 256gb I guess)... any idea to reduce it?

Comment: @Covepe Several ways in fact. Can you choose smaller datatypes e.g. (int32 is smaller than int64, which is the same size as float64, but only half the size of float128)?  You can also combine this approach with chunks (that is, use the first N rows in b, then the next set of N rows, as suggested in the other answer). Perhaps you can also use the einstein summation index, np.einsum, if the numbers are integers or never smaller than 1 in absolute terms (as then the minimum row-wise sum of squares reduces to the minimum sum of absolute values, squared, which you can express with einsum).

Comment: Note that if your memory is full, parallelizing won't help at all. You basically have one process hogging all the available memory, so sequentially going over the chunks could still work.

Answer (score 0):

If the tasks are too tiny, then tohe multiprocessing overhead will be your bottleneck and you will win nothing.

If the amount of data per task that you have to pass to a worker or that the worker has to return then you will also not win a lot (or even win nothing)

If you have 10.000 tiny tasks, then I recommend to create a list of meta tasks.
Each meta task would consist of executing for example 20 tiny tasks.

```
meta_tasks = []
for idx in range(0, len(tiny_tasks), 20):
    meta_tasks.append(tiny_tasks[idx:idx+20])
```

Then pass the meta tasks to your worker pool.

Comment: Couldn't the `chunksize` argument of the `.starmap` method be used to similar effect?

Comment: possible. I must admit I never looked at .starmap 
Don't have time now have to leave will look at it later. whether this could help to improve the anser.

The main idea is to reduce execute taska, that need considerably longer than the exchange / scheduling overhead and to try to split tasks such, that the least amount of data is being exchanged